# CakePHP not caching view

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

I'm trying to cache a heavy-loading page (where it has lots of queries from the database, takes 30-45 secs to get fully loaded to view and display) but have no luck so far.

What I did was quite basic as guided in the documentation, but somehow it just doesn't work.

1. Enable `Cache.check` and `CacheDispatcher`
2. Enable the helper in the controller as follow

   ```
   App::uses('AcucountAppController', 'Acucount.Controller');

   class WipReportsController extends AcucountAppController
   {
       public $helpers = array('Cache');
       public $cacheAction = array(
          'view' => 3600,
          'index' => 3600
       );

       function isAuthorized()
       {
             switch($this->request->action)
             {
                 case 'index':
                 case 'ajax':
                 case 'ajax_breakdown_detail':
                 return $this->Access->check('AcuCount');
                 break;
             }
       }

       // more....
   }
   ```

I also created a `views` directory under `app/tmp/cache` as well.

However, after running the page, it doesn't seem to get cached, the loading speed is still horribly slow.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think the problem is the query and not the view. CakePHP handles each tables in its own way  (the CakePHP way). Have you check all your queries? Do you always get all the fields in tables (including irrelevant fields that is not needed in the view)? You can always specify in your query which field is only needed in your process or view ` 'fields' => array('Model.field1', 'DISTINCT Model.field2'),`

Comment: If your page is taking 45 seconds to render caching isn't completely going to fix your issue as every time the cache expires someone is going to be hit by this slow load time. You should investigate improving the code/queries to improve performance. Also, is it possible to load some content in after page is rendered using AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

I think in that case you should go with memcache and redis.

[memcache](http://memcached.org/)
[redis](http://redis.io/)